# Android Studio, unknown error while setting up AdMob + cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

In my build.grade, when I put in the code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

An error comes up that says:

```
Error:(35, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

Why is this?? Its messing up my entire project. Here is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.stephenshettler.laughsoundboard"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this in the project's `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
```

When it comes to cannot resolve the symbol 'R', Simply clean or Rebuild the project or Invalidate/Restart like Firdoesh mentioned.

Comment: This is likely to be the right answer. 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' is the latest version, though.

Answer (score -1):

For this you can try putting `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'` this in gradle, it does the same job.
and for `R` go to File > Invalidate/Restart